# Inconsistent results with toCharArray and UTF-16

Tags: java, utf-16, chinese-locale

I'm still trying to wrap my head around the unicode handling and encoding of Chinese characters in Java, maybe someone can explain what I'm seeing in my debugger. I was hoping I can keep it simple and not delve into `codePoints` or use `getBytes` and simple stick with `toCharArray`. I retrieve strings with Chinese characters from either a web API/page or from a Google sheet. My understanding is that this is all handled internal within Java as UTF-16 (hidden from the user). I seem to (reliably) get 2 (Java) `chars` per Chinese character, even stuff like question marks and punctuation. When convert the string to a char array via `toCharArray` I seem to almost always see a leading 'u200b' (white space) and then the actual character with the correct unicode. (I know this is more complex and I probably phrase that wrong).

```
char[] FW_Array = tmpChar.toCharArray();
```

But here is my actual question, I seem to get only a single (Java) `char` for '-' in the first case, where as for the (I assume) same character I get two (Java) `char` in the second case. How come ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your strings seem to contain some zero-width-spaces, U+200B. They represent word-boundaries. If you remove them, the resulting strings will contain three characters. `str.replaceAll("\u200b", "")`

Comment: my problem is that I get the string 'as is' and I have to process it. So I need to know in advance whether I can rely on 2 chars per character or not. So you're saying the same 3 chars could be 3 Java character , 4,5, or 6 depending on boundary spacing ? I could probably filter the 200b out ?

Comment: The length of the char array will be equal to the length of the string. Check in the debugger: `tmpChar.length()`

Comment: but that doesn't tell me where the actual characters are , that's why I want to understand why there are the 200b and what drives it

Comment: Let me repeat: they were in the string `tmpChar` since the beginning, only you couldn't see them, because they are _zero-width_ spaces.